# Informatica Powercenter: How to run a XSLT transform on a XML document

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a complex XML document that the informatica XML parser struggles with "normalizing", how can I run a XML transformation such as XSLT to simplfy it prior to sending it into the XML parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use the standard Java transform and use the standard `javax.xml.transform` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html) to perform the transformation.

To do this add a Java Transform to your flow

[image]

In the `Import Packages` pane, import the required java packages

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
```

In the `Helper Code` pane we construct a transformer object. As I understand non static fields are created per instance, so there should be no concurrency issues. (***comments***?)

[image]

```
private final Transformer transformer = getNewTransformer();

public Transformer getNewTransformer()
{ 
  // /opt/informatica/infadev/DataTransformation
  final String IFCMPath = System.getenv("IFCONTENTMASTER_HOME"); 
  final String xslt = IFCMPath + "/ServiceDB/xst/mytransform.xslt";
  logInfo("Using XSLT File" + xslt);
  try{
   return TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
  } catch(TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
    logError("Could not create TransformerFactory with xslt " + xslt );

  }
  return null;
}
```

Finally we execute the transform on the incoming xml document by executing the transform method on the transformer object.

[image]

```
if( transformer == null ) {
    failSession("Transformer was null");
}

//final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//final long endTime;

try {
    //logInfo("Recieved xml with size " + xmlin.length() );
    // logInfo("Recieved xml " + xmlin );
    final StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlin);
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(reader),new StreamResult(writer));
    xmlout = writer.toString();
   // logInfo("xmlout  " + xmlout  );
} catch (Exception e) {
     incrementErrorCount(1);
     logError(e.getMessage());
     logError(xmlin);
} 

//finally { 
//  endTime = System.nanoTime(); 
//} 

//final long duration = endTime - startTime; 
//logInfo("Duration  " + duration / 1000000000.0 );
```